# Is it possible to draw vertical indent lines like in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to draw vertical lines in the editor that descend from the start of an indented statement, like in IntelliJ IDEA?

```
public...
|    while...
|    |
|    |    for...
|    |    |
```

Or if not natively, is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use vertical bars as indent marker character AFAIK, however, in Preferences > General > Editor > Text Editors, you can enable whitespaces markers, and tabs can be rendered as » , well aligned and so on, providing I believe a similar feeling than the | of intellij